# In ExactTarget AMPscript, how can I include a variable with a link inside a string variable and have the link tracked?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

This has been killing me all day today. I have an email that has two layers of variables in the AMPscript at the top. First, all of the links are put into variables, like this:

```
Set @HomePage = Concat('https://www.xxx.htm',@Append2)
Set @ContactUs = Concat('https://www.yyy.htm',@Append2)
Set @Login = Concat('https://www.zzz.htm',@Append2)
```

Next, I have blocks of copy to appear in the email dynamically depending on some attributes about the email recipient:

```
Set @dynamicIntro = CONCAT("Congratulations, blah blah blah xxx Plan Shopping.<br /><br />Don't miss out blah blah blah. And discover ways to earn even more by <a href=""",RedirectTo(@Login),""">logging into your account</a> blah blah blah.<br /><br />")
```

Now, in the body of the email, I call the dynamicIntro variable that was set up top. I've tried calling it with a v() or with a TreatAsContent(), but no matter what I do, the copy block does not track the link (ie, redirect from ET's servers with something like "`http://click.mydomain.com/qs?c1234545667743`").

There must be some way to have the link tracked like all the other links in the email. Maybe using regions?  Can anyone advise?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, I turned the string variable into two, one for everything before the link and one for everything after it. Then, in the HTML, I am calling them inline like this:

```
 %%=v(@firststring)=%% <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@Login)=%%">logging into your account</a> %%=v(@secondstring)=%%.
```

That works for now.

Comment: I think the trick here is the `RedirectTo()` function isn't getting properly called and output, so you are presenting OMM with a string that happens to have a link.

Comment: If there is a way to call the `RedirectTo()` function that will actually redirect the link so it can be tracked, please just let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `RedirectTo(TreatAsContent(@Login))`.  I think it's going to require that or it will just be a string when pulled initially.

Comment: Hi Kelly J Andrews, I just tried that but no luck.  To be clear, put the RedirectTo(TreatAsContent(@Login)) in the @dynamicIntro var using a CONCAT() as above. Then in the HTML, I called it using either v() or TreatAsContent() again. Sent the test email to myself and hovered over the link, and it just a flat link to the destination, not redirected off ET. Is there anything else I should be doing?  Or maybe not use CONCAT()? Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are you sending the test email? through a standard send?

Comment: No, I go to Send Preview and send the test through there. But other links in the email are tracked when I do it that way, I'm not sure... Do you think that the test send may not track the same way as a live send?

Comment: You are technically doing a live send - not sure why this isn't getting built out - I'll do some testing and see if I can get it to render.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As a workaround, turning the string variable into two, one for everything before the link and one for everything after it. Then, in the HTML, I call them inline %%=v(@firststring)=%% <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@Login)=%%">logging into your account</a> %%=v(@secondstring)=%%. That works. I think the problem has to do with whether the declaration is in the %%[]%% or inline %%==%%.

Comment: Not sure this is the best answer - I'm working through it to find a better solution.

Comment: I think this may actually be the best solution - unable to get it to work any other way.  Fill it in as an answer, then in a couple days check the mark so we know it's been answered.  Thanks for participating!